# How to bind data in title element using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm learning Angular.js and I set `<title>{{title}}</title>` and I try to change that using select element

```
<select ng-model="user.title">
    <option value="Lorem">Lorem</option>
    <option value="Ipsum">Ipsum</option>
    <option value="Dolor">Dolor</option>
</select>
```

I try `ng-change` and `ng-select` with `set()`

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'hello'; // this set the title
    $scope.set = function() {
        $scope.title = $scope.user.title; // this not
    };
}
```

THe function don't work, but it work when I just set it without a function.

I also try to create change directive:

```
app.directive('change', function() {
    console.log('change');
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(arguments);
            element[0].onChange = function() {
                scope[attrs[0]]();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

but this too don't work. Console.log don't execute at all.

Comment: Check out CSharp's response http://stackoverflow.com/a/24921980/243034

It will allow your website to be indexed properly and display in search results with a correct default rather than appearing as {{application.title}} (or whatever you choose.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything should work fine without extra code:

```
<html data-ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{title}}
    <select ng-model="title">
      <option value="Lorem">Lorem</option>
      <option value="Ipsum">Ipsum</option>
      <option value="Dolor">Dolor</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

And that's all. [Here is a pen.](http://cdpn.io/bwknB)

Comment: No, that's a codepen policy. It does not show actual title as the pen is loaded in iframe (and title is appended as first child to the body). Dig to it with dev tools and see it is changing, or try the example on yor own. (I use yeoman with angular generator for quick tests).

Answer (score 19):

When dealing with the title tag you should use [ng-bind-template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate) so you don't see the expression in its raw state `{{someVar}}` before Angular has a chance to kick in. You can add the initial text of the title within the title tag and it will be overwritten by your template.

```
<html data-ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title ng-bind-template="My App - {{title}}">My App - Default Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{title}}
    <select ng-model="title">
      <option value="Lorem">Lorem</option>
      <option value="Ipsum">Ipsum</option>
      <option value="Dolor">Dolor</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I additionally had to add  `<head ng-controller"myController">` attribute to the `head` element to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Use $rootScope

```
.when('/', {
   templateUrl: '/templates/page/home.html',
   controller: ['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
      $rootScope.title = 'Учитель24.рф';
 }]});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since @madhead gave you an awesome answer, I just want to shed some light on your question about why your code doesn't work.

You can definitely use `ng-change`, please take a look at this code. Your approach is very close, and I guess maybe you missed something?

```
<ul ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>{{title}}</div>
    <select ng-model="user.title" ng-change="set()">
        <option value="Lorem">Lorem</option>
        <option value="Ipsum">Ipsum</option>
        <option value="Dolor">Dolor</option>
    </select>
</ul>

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.set = function () {
        $scope.title = $scope.user.title;
    };
}
```

***I want to point out one thing.*** If you test in jsfiddle, don't use `<title>{{title}}</title>`, use `<div>{{title}}</div>` instead. Somehow *title* tag will not show correctly in the demo window.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GBGMD/)**</kbd>

Comment: I have exactly the same thing but I set ng-app and ng-controller to html object. If I set `$scope.title` in controler the title change but not if I put it into a function.

Comment: `ng-app` can be set in `<html>`, `ng-controller` should go with `<body>` I guess, please try.

Comment: Both jsFiddle and Codepen load results in iframes, so the `<head>` section cannot be correctly tested with these awesomes.

Comment: @jcubic I think you actually brought up a very interesting question about how to update the meta fields in the html head....hmm...I am not sure, maybe there is some hacky solution. Maybe you should reword the question to ask how to bind data in `<title>` instead?

Comment: @sza Not a problem to update them, but what is the reason? Keywords and description are read by bots; updating cache policy / charset with Angular sounds a bit freaky.

Comment: @madhead there is a reason to update the title along with the url.

Comment: @sza Updated the question and added some more explanations.

Comment: @jcubic ok. I thought, you, guys, were talking about `<meta>`. Can you show us full html, with `<html>`, `<head>` and all the stuff, because the devil is in the details.

Comment: @jcubic I am sort of lost... but I am glad you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out one solution to set title in `<title>` tag.

main.js :

```
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
      when("/faq", {
      controller: "MYCtrl",
      templateUrl: "../assets/templates/faq.html",
      title: "FAQ"
    });  

}]);


app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function( $location, $rootScope ){
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
    $rootScope.title = currentRoute.title;
  });
}]);
```

application.html.erb:

`<title ng-bind="'MYAPP - ' + $root.title"></title>`