# Chrome browser history file not catching dynamic title

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

So we're re-writing our app in angularjs, and running into new and interesting issues - like client-side routed spas and the browser history titles.

Following a few posts on here, we made the title tag a directive, and update it with a new value based on the route.

e.g.

```
<title ng-cloak>{{getTitle()}}</title>
```

The odd tidbit that got pointed out is that while the Back and Forward buttons always show the correct, final title resolution the Chrome History file is much more spotty.  About 30% of the time, Chrome shows

July 19,2016 10:52AM <favicon.ico> {{getTitle()}}

So there's obviously a little time between when the page renders and the history entry gets written (otherwise it would be 100% of the time).

Anyone know how to control this better?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24921980/4875631

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link.  A couple of questions though - shouldn't ng-cloak have covered some of the ground of ng-bind-template?  I thought ng-cloak was supposed to hide things until angular evaluates them.  Chicken or egg I guess; ng-cloak has to be evaluated by angular too.  Second, if I understand correctly, ng-bind-template will probably get the expression out of my chrome history file, but is there any way to know better what chrome's window of time before writing to the history file is?

Comment: When you look at the raw HTML, it will show `<title ng-cloak>{{getTitle()}}</title>`. With simple CSS: `*[ng-cloak]`, this will simply hide the element until angular can pass over it, and change it to it's destination value, and removing `ng-cloak`. Title is one of those elements that can't simply be hidden. The browser will read the value/store it. `ng-bind-template` stores the title in there, so when passing over by the browser the title tag is simply empty.