# How to bind data in title element using Angular (2,4,whatever)?

Tags: angular, scope, page-title

This is basically the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155394/how-to-bind-data-in-title-element-using-angular-js), but I need the answer for Angular (2,4,whatever) instead of AngularJS (1.x).

I need to migrate code that used the techniques from that Angular 1.x answer (including specifically $rootScope and ngBindTemplate) to Angular 2/4 which has gotten rid of the concept of scope (global or otherwise) as well as ngBindTemplate.

So, in a nutshell, how to display data from an Angular component in an element (e.g. title element) that is not "inside" a component template?

Comment: The `Title` service provides getter and setter for the title. https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Comment: thanks, that answers my specific question. I still wonder if there is an answer to the general question of if and how to use interpolation binding on an element that is "outside" of any component (me, being a newbie to Angular vs AngularJS)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Title service. It is part of the angular framework. I usually set it up in the constructor of the main page component. https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title